# Time delay for a new NSG rule become effective

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-nsg

When i add a new rule to my NSG, it takes some time until it becomes effective. This is confusing because on a few occasions, I thought my rules are not working and started to keep changing things.

Is there any way to find when a new NSG rule start to be effective?
If not, there any documentation explains average time delay until a new nsg rule become effective?

Answer (score 0):

I checked by adding a NSG rule for the VM but couldn't find a time delay.

If you are facing the issue , you can diagnose if your security rule has become effective or not by following the steps mentioned in the below document.

**Reference:**

[Diagnose a virtual machine network traffic filter problem | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/diagnose-network-traffic-filter-problem#diagnose-using-azure-portal)

**Note:**  If you still face the issue , Please create a Support request to Azure , for assisted troubleshooting. You can go to (Help+support) and create a new technical support request.